# SQL Count data with same detail

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table header as

```
Id_header                  | Invoice_number
------------------------------------------------------- 
KG001TEI5                  | 00000001 
RU024GHE4                  | 00000002 
MK842LGS9                  | 00000003
STH4SFG92                  | 00000004
```

and table detail as

```
Id_detail        | Id_header     | Item
------------------------------------------------------- 
KSJ234SDG        | 00000001      | Item01 
URGK4K5K4        | 00000001      | Item02 
KJ53JL5KK        | 00000002      | Item01
QSGKJRU9G        | 00000002      | Item03
MNB4598SG        | 00000003      | Item01
IMB49KS4G        | 00000003      | Item02
GK2GO9KG4        | 00000004      | Item01
BS489G45G        | 00000004      | Item02
OWG84LG43        | 00000004      | Item03
```

I want to calculate how many data that have the same detail item.
for example, the result of what I want should be :

```
Invoice_number             | total
--------------------------------------------------------
00000001                   |    2
00000002                   |    1
00000004                   |    1
```

I have to try to select data with this query

```
select count(1), d.Id_header
from detail d 
where d.Item in ('Item01', 'Item02')
group by d.Id_header
having count(*) = 2;
```

this is a db fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b990238c3aaae3d1d39280e59ca0b0e

but it was too much data and I need to record it manually, is there a query that can solve my problem?

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "same detail item".  Nor does your query return anything similar to what you appear to be asking for.

Comment: yeah my query doesnt solve the problem, i dont know what to do

Comment: I want to count data that have the exact same detail item

Comment: 1.What is the key between header and detail table?2.Which column in table 2 represent the "same detail item" you are referring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want headers that have exactly the same items.  If so, you can do what you want with two levels of aggregation:

```
select items, group_concat(id_header) as headers, count(*) as num_headers
from (select d.id_header, group_concat(d.item order by d.item) as items
      from details d
      group by d.id_header
     ) d
group by items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Accorgingly to the data posted on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b990238c3aaae3d1d39280e59ca0b0e)...

If you want to join data from `header` and `detail` table then get `count(d.Id_header)`, try this:

```
select h.Invoice_number, count(d.Id_header) AS total
  from header h INNER JOIN detail  d ON h.Id_header = d.Id_header
  group by h.Invoice_number;
```

result:

```
Invoice_number  total
00000001    2
00000002    2
00000003    2
00000004    3
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bca7446b4a9cb1f49cd23934fa90cb0f)